# Postscribe.js issue in IE8

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

I am using Postscribe.js(https://github.com/krux/postscribe) to add a script to head section.It is working fine in Mozilla & Chrome except IE8,IE7. Any idea to fix it?

below is script

```
 var scriptTag = '<script type="text/javascript" src="js/' + FILENAMETOBEADDED.Js + '"><\/script>';
            postscribe('#Head1', scriptTag);
```

Comment: Getting error "Could not set the innerHTML property. Invalid target element for this operation.  postscribe.js, line 575 character 7"

Comment: Does an element with an ID of `Head1` exist in your document _when the above code executes_? Selectors are case sensitive. Should it maybe be `#head1`?

Answer (score 0):

I just replaced some code from the postscribe.js file. The error is due to the "InnerHtml" property of the element which does not work for IE browser . In Postscribe.js file there is one line

**"this.proxyRoot.innerHTML = chunk.html"**  . So you need to replace the line with following code :

```
      **var newdiv = document.createElement("div");
      newdiv.innerHTML = chunk.html;
      this.proxyRoot.appendChild(newdiv);**
```

That works fine for me.